# Access OpenVPN-restricted website with Testcafe

Tags: testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe, openvpn

There's a website that can only be accessed if I have an OpenVPN Connect 2.1.3.111 profile running. I need to access this website using Testcafe, but so far I haven't found any documentation regarding using Testcafe with VPNs. Is there something I might have missed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Testing a website served via an OpenVPN connection is the same as testing a website hosted on your machine or an Internet server. You can connect to your VPN network with your VPN client and start testing. However, sometimes TestCafe can't automatically detect an IP address that should be used to serve a tested website when your machine is connected to multiple networks. In this case, try to specify the `--hostname localhost` option when starting TestCafe.