# Testcafe Initial Set up

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I get the error `Safari can't open the page "https://localhost:52169/browser/connect/r5cJvcm" because Safari can't establish a secure connection to the server "localhost"`

When I try to execute this

`testcafe safari TestFile2.js --hostname localhost`

The above command does work with chrome however if I try to execute without specifying the `--hostname localhost` it throws the error `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`.

How do I get the initial setup properly done to execute testcafe tests

And yes I need to execute the tests while I am connected to VPN

I did try to enable the TestCafe Browser Tools in System Preferences -> Security & Privacy -> Privacy -> Automation and screenrecording. But that did not help.

Answer (score 0):

It is necessary to specify [the `--hostname` option](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/reference/command-line-interface.html#--hostname-name) in the case of the VPN connection. It should work in all browsers. For more details please refer to the following thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56219385/10448174.